# Display the number of movies per genre

Tags: mysql, sql

I have hopefully a simple question. Using SQL statements, how do I get the number of movies per genre. Below is a screenshot of the database. It has three tables, **genres**, **movies**, and **moies_has_genres**.

**movies_has_genres** consists of the **movieID** and the **idgenres**. Many movies have many genres.

Any help would be appreciated!

[image: movieData schema]

Below is some data from the table, just to get a look at the type of data.

[image: movieData sample data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must left join `genres` and `movies_has_genres` only (the left join just in case there is a genre without movies) and `group by idgenres` to count:

```
select g.idgenres, g.title,
  count(m.movies_movieid) as counter
from genres g left join movies_has_genres m
on m.genres_idgenres = g.idgenres
group by g.idgenres, g.title
```

Because as you say *many movies have many genres* the total sum of these counters may be greater than the total number of movies.

Comment: Thanks so much! I think I need to do a little more research on joins.